# How do I extract the operand from this byte? Using two's complement

Tags: c, byte, twos-complement

I currently have the code:

```
int getOperand(unsigned char b) {
    int operand = b & 0x3F;
    return operand;
}
```

'b' is an 8 bit binary number that is read in from a byte file. The 2 most significant bits of 'b' is the OPCODE and the last 6 bits are the OPERAND. I currently have this code setup to take the last 6 bits of 'b' and store them in the variable 'operand'. The problem I am currently having is that I do not know how to extract the OPERAND as a signed operand. Currently the number that is returned is only unsigned. Therefore how can I edit the code so that it returns a signed number instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume you are just storing the last 6 bits of a negative byte that fits in a 6 bit signed value using your machines native 2's complement convention for representing negative numbers, then you check if the sign bit is set in your 6 bit value, and then extend the sign bits.

```
return (b & 0x20) ? b | ~0x3F : b & 0x3F;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NCoJAFIX3PsXBKByomHLX786naKMzow7UVWYUhLJXt5vSIqK7PN93DletCqWGmSV1bbXBwTfaVuvyNFhqkEcteVuQ0VBl6pCJ4B6Az5mmdYQowwKy20qBMzI88JRdnGCHKY@TfdCPQ7fUsv1pf4@SKXBkO2H7l9aVH6ncTLR2vJdH4VxfKFzyh1wX4g/j8pv1wws)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I am currently having is that I do not know how to extract
>   the OPERAND as a signed operand.

The C standard doesn't mandate any particular way of representing negative signed numbers. In most implementations, negative signed integers are stored in what is called two's complement. The other major way of storing negative signed numbers is called one's complement.

The code below assumes that entered number is entered as a signed number where the sign bit is stored as a bit 5 `(0x20)`. This is called one's complement representation. For some applications it is easier to code operands that way.
Example:

```
#define NEGATIVE_SIGN      0x0C
#define ONE                0x01
#define TWO                0x02

#define MINUS_ONE    (NEGATIVE_SIGN | ONE)
#define MINUS_TWO    (NEGATIVE_SIGN | TWO)
```

Then OPERAND number is transformed to full 8 bit `signed char` in two's complement representation.

```
// INPUT: OPERAND in one's complement representation of the negative value.
// Using 6 bits one can represent numbers from  -31 to 31.
// returning `signed char` is presented in two's complement representation.

    signed char getOperand(unsigned char b) {
        unsigned char operand = b & 0x3F;
        unsigned char sign = 0x20 & operand;
        unsigned char number =  0x1F & operand;

        if(sign)
        {
            number = (~number) +1;   // Conversion to Two's Complement     
        }

        return number;
    }


//  5 4 3 2 1 0


int main (){
    printf("%d\n",  getOperand(0x21)); // negative one
    printf("%d\n",  getOperand(0x22)); // -2
    printf("%d\n",  getOperand(0x2F)); // negative 15
    printf("%d\n",  getOperand(0x1F | 0x20 ) ); // negative -31    
    printf("%d\n",  getOperand(0x1F ) );        // positive 31 

  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-1
-2
-15
-31
31
```

Comment: @chux  You are right. Explicitly stating `signed` will never hurt! Code has been improved. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0x3F == -1`and `0x20 == -32` ?

Comment: You are doing some one's complement calculation. For two's complement the msb is not simply a sign bit.

Comment: @Gerhardh The OP has not specified the input representation of the `OPERAND`. He only specified the desired output representation. The code assumes  that `OPERAND`, as you noted correctly, is in _one's complement representation_ . I have added more explanation to my example to clarify the approach. Thank you for your good comment.

Comment: As the title of the question mentions two's complement, I would assume that representation should be used.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks! That might be the case which is well covered by jxh. He stated: _If we assume you are just storing the last 6 bits [...] using your machines native 2's complement convention for representing negative numbers..._ I assumed  the other alternative: 1's compliment for the input and 2's complement for output.